# Can someone help clarify matrix multiplication for me?

Tags: linear-algebra

In my Linear Algebra studies i'm finding intuitive problems with how i perceive matrices and would like some clarification.

For example, if I were to be transforming the basis of some vectors, and I wanted to get some new vectors in terms of the old basis, I need the inverse transformation right? If this is incorrect, please correct me, but for the sake of my understanding, does it matter if I were to multiply out of order? Do i need to do that last inverse multiplication last or could i do it first. For example, is AxA^-1 the same as A^-1xA?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: $A\times B$ is not necessarily going to be the same thing as $B\times A$.  These can be different.  Putting on your socks before you put on your shoes makes sense.  Putting on your shoes before you put on your socks does not.  As for the specific example of $A\times A^{-1}$, by definition this is equal to $I$ which is also seen to be equal to $A^{-1}\times A$.  If rather than multiplication, this is a vector $x$ in the middle, then yes it does matter.  $AxA^{-1}$ can be different than $A^{-1}xA$

Comment: This celebrated video series may not immediately answer your question but I'm sure it will overall help if you haven't already seen it: https://www.3blue1brown.com/topics/linear-algebra

Comment: I suggest you do some reading in a good textbook. There are so many on the web that discuss these topics.

Comment: yes Jmoravitz that is perfect, thank you! sorry for confusion guys

Answer (score 0):

You're asking a lot of different things in a way that's not entirely clear what your specific question is, but to address one part of your question:

Matrix multiplication is not commutative, i.e. if $A$ and $B$ are matrices then in general $AB \neq BA$. However, it *is* true that if $A$ is an invertible matrix, then $A^{-1}A = AA^{-1} = I$.